# How to wirte id3v2.3 with taglib

Tags: c++, taglib, id3v2

When i use the taglib to write id3v2 tag to mp3,the taglib write id3v2.4 as default. But on windows,the media player and explorer can not parse it.

How could i solve this?

code like this:

```
TagLib::MPEG::File* mpegfile//i've already new the instance
TagLib::ID3v2::Tag* id3v2tag = mpegfile->ID3v2Tag();
id3v2tag->setTitle("taylor swift");
mpegfile->save;
```

the header version is id3 v2.4
but i wanna save as id3 v2.3

Comment: Can you give a little more information about your problem? Can you post any code you've written, so the community can take a look?

Answer (score 1):

The `save` method of the `MPEG::File` has several overloads like this:

```
bool save(int tags, bool stripOthers, int id3v2Version);
```

You therefore best don't simply call `mpegfile->save;`
but

```
mpegfile->save( TagLib::MPEG::File::AllTags, true, 3);
```

For every overload see the [source file](https://github.com/taglib/taglib/blob/master/taglib/mpeg/mpegfile.h)